# PnP-Search Result webpart doesn't show profile picture in the cards

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, pnp, people-search, pnp-search-webparts

I use SharePoint online and I have a Communication site with the PnP-SearchResults on it.

In my PnP-SearchResult web-part, it doesn't display the profile pictures.

When I open a page, my picture is displayed:

[image]

But not in the card of the PnP-SearchResult:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your "Managed Card fields" details too?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did anyone find the solution for this one?